# Using await with fastapi

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, fastapi

I’ve followed the fastapi documentation but still get a error message when using this code:

```py
async def set_pizza_status_to_ready(order: Order, db: Session):
    await baking_pizzas(order, db, 60)
    pizzas = get_all_pizzas_in_order(order, db)
    for pizza in pizzas:
        pizza.status = 'READY'

def baking_pizzas(order: Order, db: Session, minutes: float):
    # simulate baking duration and set pizzas to ready afterwards
    time.sleep(minutes * 60)
```

```py
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'set_pizza_status_to_ready' was never awaited
```

Comment: use asyncio.sleep instead of time.sleep, because time.sleep is blocking and not async

Comment: The warning is probably generated by code somewhere else that calls `set_pizza_status_to_ready`. Can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `await` expression before the coroutine.

```py
await set_pizza_status_to_ready()
```

It is not a function but a coroutine, it yields. You need to `await` it.

But there are some restrictions. You can not use the `await` keyword if you are not calling a coroutine inside a coroutine function.

There are also some workarounds for this

You can use `asyncio.run(my_coroutine)` to run a coroutine inside a function.

Comment: "You can not use the await keyword in a function." are you referring to sync functions? If so, you should specify.

Comment: @SuperStormer coroutines are not functions.

Comment: `async def` creates an async *function*.

Comment: You are wrong, check the second part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410635/python-fastapi-async-variable-sharing/65447000#65447000) which i explained more deeply. `async def` is just a syntactic sugar. Python's official documentation for [**coroutines**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) also uses `async def` syntax but never calls it function. They are just different like how a method is different than a function, completely different abstractions going on.

Comment: [Python language spec](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#coroutine-function-definition) call it a coroutine *function*. In addition, the docs page you linked also has this: `a coroutine function: an async def function;`.

Comment: Yes, that's what function means. See [**glossary**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine), they are also different. I just agree on making it **coroutine function** makes more clear, since everybody does not know the internals. But if we are calling it a coroutine function for functions we declared with `async def`, then we should call subroutine functions for the function that we declared with `def` because that's how computer science works.